# How to render a Chart.js base64Image without diplaying the chart in Angular

Tags: angular, chart.js, pdfmake

I have an issue I'm thinking on how to solve. I have three bootstrap tabs and on each, a chart is rendered via Chart.js.

I want to make it possible for the user to export all charts after page is loaded via button click.

Everything works well for one tab. Like this:

```
var canvasEquity = document.getElementById("myChart") as HTMLCanvasElement;
var imgEquity    = canvasEquity.toDataURL("image/png");
var iframe = "<iframe 
               width='100%' height='100%' 
               src='" + imgEquity + "'>
               </iframe>"

pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

var pdfDocument = {
content: [ 
  {
    image: imgEquity,
    width: 350,
    height: 200
  }
]};

pdfMake.createPdf(pdfDocument).open();
```

I get a nice pdf with one chart which is currently open. The chart is rendered OnInit  like this:

```
renderChart() {

if (this.myChart) 
  this.myChart.destroy();

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels :this.equityDates,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Closed Equity',
      data: this.equity,
    }]
    }
```

The other charts are obviously rendered (onClick) when their tabs are opened. I tried rendering them manually into the DOM, by calling their methods just like the one above and also by calling the Chart.js APi render menthod on load as well however I get an error. They are simply not there, the data URL is empty!

However if you open the tab at least once and go back to the previous tab the data URL appears. Does anybody know how to solve this programmatically so you can just click a button and all the charts would render without the need of putting them all out on one page. Thank you.

Here is also a sample of the bootstrap part of the tab code.

```
<div>
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

<li class="active">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#equity">Equity</a>
</li>

<li (click)="renderChartDD()">
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#dd">Drawdowns</a>
</li>

 <li (click)="renderMonthlyRevChart()" >
 <a data-toggle="tab" href="#monthlyEquity">Monthly Revenue</a>
 </li>

</div>



              <div class="tab-content">

                <div id="equity" class="tab-pane active">                      
                      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>                    
                </div>

                <div id="dd" class="tab-pane">
                    <canvas id="myChartDD"></canvas>
                </div>

                <div id="monthlyEquity" class="tab-pane">
                    <canvas id="myChartMonthlyEquity"></canvas>
                </div>

               </div>
```